# Using the divergence theorem for $F=curl(\langle y,x,-z\rangle)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use the divergence theorem to evaluate $\int_{}^{}\int_{S}^{} F. NdS$ where $F=curl(\langle y,x,-z\rangle)$ and S is the hemisphere $z=\sqrt{4-x^2 -y^2}$ together with $x^2+y^2\leq 4$ in $xy$ plane.

Now the force given here is $F=curl(\langle y,x,-z\rangle)$

I need divergence of this force but I know $div(cur F) = 0$ always so the final answer in this case will be $0$?

Comment: Yes..answer is $0$ and if you notice F itself is $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @omkarGirkar also it's true that $div(curl F ) = 0 $ always ?

Comment: Yes,it is always true..